# lapply fail, but function works fine for each individual input arguments

Tags: r

Many thanks in advance for any advices or hints. 
I'm working with data frames. The simplified coding is as follows:
`

```
f<-funtion(name){
    x<-tapply(name$a,list(name$b,name$c),sum)
1)  y<-dataset[[deparse(substitute(name))]]
    #where dataset is an already existed list object with names the same as the 
    #function argument. I would like to avoid inputting two arguments.
    z<-vector("list",n) #where n is also defined already
2)  for (i in 1:n){z[[i]]<-x[y[[i]],i]}
    ...
}
lapply(list_names,f)
```

`

The warning message is:
  In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

and the output is incorrect. I tried debugging and found the conflict may lie in line 1) and 2). However, when I try f(name) it is perfectly fine and the output is correct. I guess the problem is in lapply and I searched for a while but could not get to the point. Any ideas? Many thanks!

### The structure of the data

Thanks Joran. Checking again I found the problem might not lie in what I had described. I produce the full code as follows and you can copy-paste to see the error.

```
n<-4
name1<-data.frame(a=rep(0.1,20),b=rep(1:10,each=2),c=rep(1:n,each=5),
                  d=rep(c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a91"),each=2))
name2<-data.frame(a=rep(0.2,20),b=rep(1:10,each=2),c=rep(1:n,each=5),
                  d=rep(c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a91"),each=2))
name3<-data.frame(a=rep(0.3,20),b=rep(1:10,each=2),c=rep(1:n,each=5),
                  d=rep(c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a91"),each=2))
#d is the name for the observations. d corresponds to b.
dataset<-vector("list",3)
names(dataset)<-c("name1","name2","name3")
dataset[[1]]<-list(c(1,2),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4,5,10),c(4,5,8))
dataset[[2]]<-list(c(1,2,3,5),c(1,2),c(1,2,10),c(2,3,4,5,8,10))
dataset[[3]]<-list(c(3,5,8,10),c(1,2,5,7),c(1,2,3,4,5),c(2,3,4,6,9))
f<-function(name){
  x<-tapply(name$a,list(name$b,name$c),sum)
  rownames(x)<-sort(unique(name$d)) #the row names for 
  y<-dataset[[deparse(substitute(name))]]
  z<-vector("list",n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    z[[i]]<-x[y[[i]],i]}
  nn<-length(unique(unlist(sapply(z,names)))) # the number of names appeared
  names_<-sort(unique(unlist(sapply(z,names)))) # the names appeared add to the matrix 
                                                # below
  m<-matrix(,nrow=nn,ncol=n);rownames(m)<-names_
  index<-vector("list",n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    index[[i]]<-match(names(z[[i]]),names_)
    m[index[[i]],i]<-z[[i]]
  }
  return(m)
}
list_names<-vector("list",3)
list_names[[1]]<-name1;list_names[[2]]<-name2;list_names[[3]]<-name3
names(list_names)<-c("name1","name2","name3")
lapply(list_names,f)
f(name1)
```

the lapply(list_names,f) would fail, but f(name1) will produce exactly the matrix I want. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Also, you shouldn't need the gymnastics of `deparse(substitute(..))`, `dataset[[name]]` should work fine.  But without your `dataset`, `n` and `list_names` we can't help much.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan and Justin. I have updated the data structure, is it more clear to you now? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No, it is not any more clear. Go back to the link Justin provided and read it carefully to learn how to provide a _reproducible_ example. We should be able to copy+paste code into an R session and run it ourselves.

Comment: Thanks again joran, the example had been added and you can copy-paste and see. As I am not sure about where the problem lies in, I tried to produce the whole coding as simple as possible in the example. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why it doesn't work

The issue is the calling stack doesn't look the same in both cases.  In `lapply`, it looks like

```
[[1]]
lapply(list_names, f) # lapply(X = list_names, FUN = f)

[[2]]
FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
```

In the expression being evaluated, `f` is called `FUN` and its argument `name` is called `X[[1L]]`.

When you call `f` directly, the stack is simply

```
[[1]]
f(name1) # f(name = name1)
```

Usually this doesn't matter, but with `substitute` it does because `substitute` cares about the name of the function argument, not its value.  When you get to

```
y<-dataset[[deparse(substitute(name))]]
```

inside `lapply` it's looking for the element in `dataset` named `X[[1L]]`, and there isn't one, so `y` is bound to `NULL`.

### A way to get it to work

The simplest way to deal with this is probably to just have `f` operate on character strings and pass `names(list_names)` to lapply.  This can be accomplished fairly easily by changing the beginning of `f` to

```
f<-function(name){
  passed.name <- name
  name <- list_names[[name]]
  x<-tapply(name$a,list(name$b,name$c),sum)
  rownames(x)<-sort(unique(name$d)) #the row names for 
  y<-dataset[[passed.name]]
# the rest of f...
```

and changing `lapply(list_names, f)` to `lapply(names(list_names),f)`.  This should give you what you want with nearly minimal modification, but you also might consider also renaming some of your variables so the word `name` isn't used for so many different things--the function `names`, the argument of `f`, and all the various variables containing `name`.